# How to provide the Write Access in Firebase without giving Read Access?

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am having a strange situation in my app where Unauthorised users can send me the messages. whereas It will be only one user who can have the read access to those messages.

I am using the `$bindto` to write on the database `(with my google logged in and google authentication enabled)` and reading it through email password authentication method .

I want that user could send the message without any authentication process.

**Is this possible**?

Comment: To allow an unauthenticated user to write to a node, just specify `".write": true` in your Firebase Security Rules for that node. I suggest spending some time reading the [Firebase documentation on the securing the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-overview). If you're still having problems, post back with a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you've tried, i.e. the minimal security rules and the read/write operation that you want to have succeed/fail.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way we can stop unautheticated user to get the data from firebase database. For this situation that I faced I was worried about that if a user download the JS file he can get the access of all my database. But there is a catch : 
Since you whitelist your IP/domain name no one other than that domain can take the access.So, even if they download your file they will no be able to get the access as request will not be from authenticated IP/domain name.

The other way is using the anonymous authentication method so that u can anyhow authenticate user and by that you can atleast have the trail of who are working or modifying your data (IP tracking access log is also useful).

Comment: This is not how Firebase Authentication and security work. There is no access control by IP.